# How to calculate a limit of a sequence of iid random varianbles

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

I have a sequence of iid random variables ${\xi_n}$ with density $p(x) = e^{-x}$ for $x>0$ and $p(x) =0$ otherwise (exponential distribution). How to prove the following?

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup \frac{\xi_n}{\ln (n)}=1$$ almost surely

where $\ln$ is the natural logarithm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but, unfortunately, it does not... If possible, I would like to get comments on how to approach this specific problem.

Comment: Did you look at the answer provided by Robert Israel? and that is not useful for you?

Comment: You use Borel-Cantelli to show $X_n/\log(n)>1$ infinitely often but $X_n/\log(n)> 1+\epsilon$ finitely often.